# How to update ToolStripStatusLabel Text from a method passing all the controls on the form

Tags: c#, statusstrip, toolstripstatuslabel

I have a method to reset some controls on my form.  I'm able to get the method to work except for the `ToolStripStatusLabel` named "tsStatusLabelInfo".  This control is not passed to the `resetForm()` method.

I believe that it is part of the StatusStrip control but I haven't figure out how to get access to the `ToolStripStatusLabel` control to update the text.

```
private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Utilities.resetForm(this);
}

public static void resetForm(Control form)
{
    foreach(Control c in GetOffSprings(form))
    {
        if (c.Name == "folderTextBox")
        {
            ((TextBox)c).Clear();
        }
        else if (c.Name == "mfrListTextBox")
        {
            ((RichTextBox)c).Clear();
        }
        else if (c.Name == "mfrListDataGridView")
        {
            ((DataGridView)c).DataSource = null;
        }
        else if (c.Name == "onlyRadioButton")
        {
            ((RadioButton)c).Checked = true;
        }
        else if (c.Name == "usRadioButton")
        {
            ((RadioButton)c).Checked = true;
        }
        else if (c.Name == "otherYearsCheckedListBox")
        {
            ((CheckedListBox)c).SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked);
            ((CheckedListBox)c).SetItemCheckState(1, CheckState.Unchecked);
        }
        else if (c.Name == "yearComboBox")
        {
            ((ComboBox)c).Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (c.Name == "tsStatusLabelInfo")
        {
            //Control never pass
        }
        else if (c.Name == "statusStrip1")
        {
            // Exception:Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            ((StatusStrip)c).Controls["tsStatusLabelInfo"].Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

//Loop through the control recursively getting all child controls
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetOffSprings(this Control @this)
{
    foreach(Control child in @this.Controls)
    {
        yield return child;

        //MessageBox.Show(child.Name);

        foreach (var offspring in GetOffSprings(child))
        {
            yield return offspring;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.controls(v=vs.110).aspx

The `Controls` collection is not used on the `ToolStrip` and `ToolStripContainer`. You should use `Items` instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.items(v=vs.110).aspx

The items on the tool strip are not `Control` objects. They are `ToolStripItem` objects. Looping recursively through the `Controls` collection will not give you access to these items.

Comment: That did it - I change the code to

((StatusStrip)c).Items["tsStatusLabelInfo"].Text = string.Empty; 

Thanks for your help!!